# Add custom files to the Nuget package so that they will appear in root directory?

Tags: xml, nuget

I'm using NuGet Version: 4.9.4.5839 .

I've already created a nuget package which I pack & push via those commands :

- `dotnet pack myproj.csproj -c Release -o .`
- `nuget push myproj.1.0.0.nupkg  <key> ....`

All Ok.

I'm able to consume that nuget package in my other projects.

But now I want to add custom files to be included .

So if someone fetches the nuget , I want that a the following directory and files will be included at the consumer's solution :

This is what I've tried:

I've created a folder and a file:

[image]

I've also created the `aaa-health-check-net-core.nuspec` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/*.txt" buildAction="none" copyToOutput="true"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="aaa\*.txt" target="contentFiles\any\any" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Ok let's `pack` and `push` .

As you can see , I do see an update. and I click it.

[image]

The result is :

[image]

**Question:**

I don't want the custom file to appear where it currently appear.
I want it to appear at the **root** of the project

How can I do that ?

Comment: I missed the nuspec section of your question previously. `PackageReference` projects should never need to use a nuspec. Instead you can use `PackagePath` in your csproj. [See the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package).

Comment: @zivkan How can i know if im using package Reference project or not. This is getting very confusing

Comment: I know it's confusing, but this is the reality we're in. We're planning on updating our docs, but don't have something good to point you to right now. Short version is that all SDK-style projects (used by, but not limited to, .NET Core) are PackageReference (PR). Traditional csproj can be either PR or PC (packages.config). If your project uses one or more NuGet packages, and you don't see a `packages.config` file in your project root, then it's PR.

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciated

Comment: There should be a past -present - future  road map for history configuration and current ones.

Comment: Our PMs periodically post roadmaps to the nuget blog. [Here's the latest one](https://blog.nuget.org/20190410/nuget-spring-2019-roadmap.html).

Comment: A "large picture" road map is useless when throwing down barriers around a blind corner in a 50mph zone.. having to deal with compatibility for a living and PR really screwed this up without a hatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't*.

Your project uses the new SDK style project, which only supports NuGet via `PackageReference`, and `PackageReference` packages can only affect build output, not project files.

A project using a traditional project file, and reference NuGet packages with `packages.config`, will copy files in the `content` directory of the package into the project on package install (but not on restore, so those files need to be checked into source control). But SDK style projects don't support `packages.config`.

*if you're feeling a little bit evil, you could include MSBuild targets which creates/copies/modifies files in the project when the target runs. But there's no target that runs on install (and even if there was, people not using Visual Studio and editing the project file with a text editor wouldn't trigger the target anyway), so the most likely target is to run on build. Say the person using your package doesn't want your text file in their project, so they delete it, but then every time they build the project, it gets recreated.

Also FYI, the dotnet cli supports pushing with `dotnet nuget push`, so you may not need to download nuget.exe just to push.

Comment: _and PackageReference packages can only affect build output, not project files_ - I'm just wondering , any reason for this ?  Is affecting project files seems like a bad practice ?

Comment: I joined the NuGet client team only a few months ago, a long time after PackageReference was designed and implemented, so I don't know the reason decisions were made. But in my opinion yes. I was frustrated in the past with a library for ASP.NET having an admin page bundled in the package that we had to delete from our production project every time we updated the package, and had to re-apply branding and usability improvements every time we updated our admin project. NuGet just isn't flexible enough for web stuff. ASP.NET Core style configuration is superior to bundling config files too.

Comment: "I was frustrated" (given to any of the decision makers) is a poor reason to make many tens of thousands of others frustrated when attempting to forward migrate. Good job PR team! (Hint: it's called backwards compatibility and/or flexibility.)